# How to use grep in Linux for multiple '&' based search

Tags: linux, oracle, shell, grep

I am trying to find out of two process are running in linux where my oracle is installed `pmon` and `smon` 
i used below command for it

```
ps -ae | grep pmon > /dev/null;echo $?
```

and

```
 ps -ae | grep smon > /dev/null;echo $?
```

now i want to optimize both commands in to single
i know there is option in `grep` as below

```
ps -ae | grep 'pmon\|smon' > /dev/null;echo $?
```

but problem here is if any of process running it returns 0 error code
but i want an `AND` based search instead. Command should return 0 only if both process running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you used something like this:

```
if ps -ae | grep -q pmon && ps -ae | grep -q smon; then
    echo "pmon and smon are running"
fi
```

The `-q` switch to grep prevents any output so you don't have to redirect to `/dev/null` yourself. If you have `pgrep`, you may be able to use that instead of piping `ps` to `grep`.

Of course, you *could* "optimise" this onto one line, optionally using another `&&` instead of an `if` but I really don't see the advantage!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
pgrep pmon > /dev/null && pgrep smon > /dev/null; echo $?
```

or

```
pgrep pmon > /dev/null && pgrep smon > /dev/null && echo both running
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

ps -ae | egrep 'pmon,smon'